# Specifying Custom Network on Regional Managed Instance Groups on GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-networking, gce-instance-group

I am exploring managed instance groups on GCP, and I am trying to create a multi-zone (regional) MIG. However, it always selects the default network, and I don't see any way to change it (I know it can change if the MIG is zonal). Is it possible to use a custom network with a regional MIG, or is that just a current limitation that it always needs to use the default?

Comment: There shouldn't be any difference between zonal and regional MIGs in this respect. Could you provide a recent screenshot/error message/etc?

Answer (score 1):

First you will need to create the [VPC Network](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-vpc) and set its dynamic routing mode to Global.

Then simple while Creating an instance group, select Create New Instance Template under Instance Template [image] and while setting the instance template choose the created network under the Networking section [image].

Comment: Hi, that works for single-zone MIGs. My issue is with multi-zone MIGs. They are always grayed out.

Comment: You were right, I have updated my answer with the multiple zones setup in the configuration. And I have not found any issue. Could you share a screenshot and or the full configuration?